# c# Text over video

Tags: c#, video, text, overlay

I've spent days googling and coding tryin to acheive the basic level of effect all media players have when showing fancy subtitles - that being text (optionally with outline/dropshadow/glow) written above a video (video being a videofile but would nice to also have option of being a videofeed eg webcam).

So far the only way I've managed to get anything over a video is either to write to a transparent picturebox above a video component which is aliased so has dodgy outline, or using the directshow.net library and the capture method from the dxtext example I have managed to actually write over a picturebox that is being spat frames of the video.  The problem here is that as soona s I add the writing commands in (video plays to picturebox fine without it) then I get slight fps hit coming accross as marginal stuttering on the video.

Does noone have a way to just write/draw over a video without taking this kind of performance hit?  Or am I going to have to resort to directx or something or just give up on this luxury?  :/  I can paste any code needed for help but I think anyone with assistance will probably be the one wanting to post code!

TIA for any input, it's doing my head in  D:

Comment: I take it you are stuck with WinForms (no WPF)?

Comment: days googling, really? You should post a couple of links to things you've looked at because there is 76 pages of answers using these search terms: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+overlay+text+on+video

Comment: I once made a pretty good performing version by rendering the text 3 times: twice in black with an offset of 2 pixels to the right and down between them and a white version in between these

Comment: Yes - days googling and coding.  Hence I tried the various approaches with no satisfactory results.  And yeah I'm stuck with winforms no wpf  :|
The best I've got is the laggy version using directshow.net library.