# Text file to video file C#

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I am planning to create a wav video file from a text file.
Basically each word will be read from the text file and will be scrolling upwards one after another. The output of the program will will be a video file.
Then anyone can play the video file.

I came across the following questions on stackoverflow:
[Convert Text to Video (mp4 or mov or flv)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764184/convert-text-to-video-mp4-or-mov-or-flv)
[c# Text over video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8017104/c-sharp-text-over-video)

But those are not much of help.
Can you please point me to some good articles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to draw a picture for each frame (painting the words into the pictures at the desired position) and then convert that series of frames into a video. There are tutorials out there on how to encode a series of pictures as video (like the one that Rahat quoted).

Answer (score 0):

Found an article that does something similar: http://en.code-bude.net/2013/04/17/how-to-create-video-files-in-c-from-single-images/